# Shopware 6.5 how to update from 6.4 by shopware-installer.phar.php

Tags: shopware6

I wanted to update shopware 6.4.20.2 to shopware 6.5.2.1 using shopware-installer.phar.php.
Follows the instructions at https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/update-guides/updating-shopware
I add the file to public catalog shopware-installer.phar.php and run in the browser address and get this screen (something styles didn't load).
[image]
I click continue and get this error
[image]
Clearing the cache didn't help
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I tried to update via composer too. However, composer update doesn't want to update to the latest version. It does not detect a newer version

Answer (score 2):

If you have additional dependencies in your composer.json (.e.g plugins from the shopware store) than you must also increase their versions to some that are Shopware 6.5 compatible.

Answer (score 2):

Let me guess, you're on Nginx?

If so, add this to the server part of your nginx config:

```
server {
[...]
    location /shopware-installer.phar.php {
        try_files $uri /shopware-installer.phar.php$is_args$args;
    }
[...]
}
```

Comment: This helped, thanks a lot. Hard to believe that it's almost impossible to find documentation on how to do shopware on nginx.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to update is by doing it from a command line. If Composer does not detect an update, then maybe you have the wrong version in `composer.json`; change your version and try re-running `composer update`.

E.g. If you have something like this:

```
"shopware/administration": "~v6.4.0",
"shopware/core": "~v6.4.0",
"shopware/elasticsearch": "~v6.4.0",
"shopware/storefront": "~v6.4.0",
```

Simply change `6.4.0` to `6.5.0`:

```
"shopware/administration": "~v6.5.0",
"shopware/core": "~v6.5.0",
"shopware/elasticsearch": "~v6.5.0",
"shopware/storefront": "~v6.5.0",
```

Then try to run `composer update`